# Proyection of a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, projection, projection-matrices

Let $W \subset \mathbb{R}^{4}$ a subspace generated by two vectors
$$W := span \left\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rbrace.
$$
Find $w \in W$ wich minimize $||w-v||$ where $v= \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4
\end{pmatrix}$. ($||\cdot ||$ is the usual norm in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

I found the projection matrix, and is

$$P= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{4}{5}
\end{pmatrix}  $$
so, $w= Pv=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{2} \\
\frac{3}{2}\\
\frac{11}{5}\\
\frac{22}{5}
\end{pmatrix}$
Am I right?, I don't know if I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct and complete.

Comment: I have this question because, I am little confuse because  I  don't know if $Pv$ and $v$ have to be perpendicular.

Comment: @Mari no, they don't have to be perpendicular. What makes $Pv$ the "orthogonal" projection is the fact that the vectors $Pv$ and $v - Pv$ are perpendicular. The idea is that $Pv$ is the component of $v$ parallel to the subspace, and $v - Pv$ is the component of $v$ perpendicular to the subspace.